# Oracle SQL group by with joined tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables

[image]

[image: appt_serv]

[image: appt]

I wish to get the APPT_NO, APPT_DATETIME, PATIENT_NO, PATIENT_FULL_NAME, TOTAL_COST where the total cost equals the max total cost recorded for one appointment

In APPT_SERV, there can be multiple rows with the same APPT_NO

Here's what I did, but it's giving group by error

```
SELECT APPT_NO, APPT_DATETIME, PATIENT_NO, 
       (CASE WHEN NVL (PATIENT_FNAME, 'NULL') != 'NULL' THEN PATIENT_FNAME || ' ' ELSE '' END) || PATIENT_LNAME AS PATIENT_FULL_NAME,
       NVL(SUM(APPTSERV_FEE), 0) + NVL(SUM(APPTSERV_ITEMCOST), 0) + NVL(SUM(SERVICE_STDFEE), 0) AS TOTAL_COST
FROM APPOINTMENT
JOIN PATIENT USING(PATIENT_NO)
JOIN APPT_SERV USING(APPT_NO)
JOIN SERVICE USING(SERVICE_CODE)
WHERE NVL(SUM(APPTSERV_FEE), 0) + NVL(SUM(APPTSERV_ITEMCOST), 0) + NVL(SUM(SERVICE_STDFEE), 0) = 
    (SELECT MAX(NVL(SUM(APPTSERV_FEE), 0) + NVL(SUM(APPTSERV_ITEMCOST), 0) + NVL(SUM(SERVICE_STDFEE), 0))
    FROM APPOINTMENT
    JOIN APPT_SERV USING(APPT_NO)
    JOIN SERVICE USING(SERVICE_CODE)
    GROUP BY APPT_NO);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Read comments within code.

I removed everything that makes code difficult to read (`NVL` function calls, `CASE` expressions, ... - include them later).

```
WITH
   appt_cost
   AS
      -- calculate total cost per each appointment and sort rows by total cost in descending order
      (  SELECT s.appt_no,
                SUM (s.apptserv_fee + s.apptserv_itemcost + s.service_stdfee)
                   AS total_cost,
                RANK ()
                   OVER (
                      ORDER BY
                         SUM (s.apptserv_fee + s.apptserv_itemcost + s.service_stdfee) DESC)
                   rn
           FROM appt_serv s
       GROUP BY s.appt_no)
-- fetch all other data you need
SELECT a.appt_no,
       a.appt_datetime,
       a.patient_no,
       p.patient_fname,
       c.total_cost
  FROM patient  p
       JOIN appointment a ON a.patient_no = p.patient_no
       JOIN appt_cost c ON c.appt_no = a.appt_no
 -- return row(s) whose total cost is equal to the highest total cost (i.e. one(s) that ranked as the highest)
 WHERE c.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Can you do this in a single select statement with subqueries?

Comment: This **is** a single select statement. CTE is just a nice option we have. If you want, you can move it into FROM clause, just substitute `join appt_cost` with `join (select s.appt_no, sum(...` (basically, the whole appt_cost query). Everything would work just the same.